# How to use p:tabMenu with Ajax

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `p:tabMenu` which is used to display tabs.

```
<p:tabMenu id="tabs" activeIndex="0" >  
    <p:menuitem value="tab1" url="/tab1.jsf" />
    <p:menuitem value="tab2" url="/tab2.jsf" />
</p:tabMenu>
```

In order to make the loading of the tabs more smooth (I don't want to see the tab blinking) can I somehow use Ajax?

Comment: If the visual aspect of the loading is what you're more interested in, simply set the `effect` attribute of the tab to any of the supported pf effects. Tabviews are ajaxified by default anyway

Answer (score 3):

Caching (`cache=true`) the tab contents will make the loading more smooth. Caching is enabled by default. In addition if you want to make an ajax call on every tab change use the `tabChange` event:

```
<p:tabMenu id="tabs" activeIndex="0" dynamic="true">

    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{tabBean.onTabChange}"/>

    <p:menuitem value="tab1" url="/tab1.jsf" />
    <p:menuitem value="tab2" url="/tab2.jsf" />
</p:tabMenu>
```

For detailed example see the [TabView - Change Listener](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/tabviewChangeListener.jsf) demo.

Answer (score 2):

Set `dynamic="true"` on your `<p:tabMenu/>`, automatically triggers an ajax request. Very visible on the primefaces demo site. Also see the [primefaces demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/tabviewHome.jsf).

EDIT: Considering your question more carefully, if it's *smoothness* in visuals you're looking for, you should set your tab `effect` parameter to any of the primefaces [effects](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/effects.jsf). My personal favourite is the `effect="slide"`